# Using integer-typed pseudo-register when other than integer type required

Tags: debugging, windbg

In my Windbg script, I have a pesudo-register defined that stores an integer. Next, there is a .writemem called from my script. The first parameter of .writemem takes the file name. I want the file name to be the value of the pseudo register.

This is the simplified version of my Windbg script that doesn't work (because the pseudo-register is integer and first parameter of .writemem expects different type than integer).

r $t0 = 0;

$$ code sequence follows might change the value of $t0

.writemem **$t0** eip L100

Answer (score 1):

You could create an alias string out of the value of the pseudo register and use that. For example:

```
0: kd> r @$t0 = 5+5
0: kd> aS /x ${/v:fileName} @$t0
0: kd> .writemem ${fileName}.txt @eip L100
Writing 100 bytes.
```

Will create a file named, "0xa.txt".

-scott

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo registers can be used with `r?` which allows to assign type to a register.

Here is an example to assign strings to the register

`r? @$t0 = (_UNICODE_STRING*) 0x0139df70+0x8`

Here is a [write up](http://analyze-v.com/?p=214) on using this.

Comment: Yeah, that'd be good but I made the above example too simple, sorry. In the real script, the $t0 is a loop variable so I have to define as I wrote it above.

Comment: Did you try look at the URL? What is that you aren't able to do?

Comment: I've taken a look at the link you provided but don't think I can use it now. There are arithemtic operations performed on $t0 and because the value of $t0 stored as integer casting the pointer to unicode string doesn't make the integer unicode string. Of course I could convert the integer to unicode string and referencing but that would make the simple script even complex. I believe there is a straightforward soultion.